# Google Sheets automatically update new row with formula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, automatic-updates

[image: Spreadsheet]
I have a sheet I am constantly adding new items on.
The current formula in column E, takes the latest price I am paying for the item.

I want to have this formula already built into any new rows added.
Here is how it currently looks:
[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvTgP.png)

I have not done any script before, but it looks like this is possible using an array formula.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Hi, would it be possible to share a copy of your spreadsheet so we have some data to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Clear out all contents of column E. Then enter in E2

```
={"Current"; ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(trim(transpose(query(transpose(F3:BQ),,rows(A3:A)))),"[^\s]+$")+0))}
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Wow, that works great!
Only issue is using regextract, I am unable to do vlookup on another workbook referencing column E
Currently the formula I had been using was:

`=iferror(VLOOKUP(A3,IMPORTRANGE("1Mu-mK3lxfRmK3_wQ4m8C_mqVY0BJOzWX4Uo01d-YZ7U","'Protein'!a3:500"),5,0),"")`

It has no problem pulling words (E2=Current), just not the prices.

Comment: Also tried Query: `=query(IMPORTRANGE("1Mu-mK3lxfRmK3_wQ4m8C_mqVY0BJOzWX4Uo01d-YZ7U","'Protein'!A3:E"),"select Col5")`

And result comes back blank same as vlookup

Comment: Check the formatting. If A3 is a number and the vlookuprange is text, convert A3 to text by adding A3&"". If would help if you could share your spreadsheet (or a mock-up).

Comment: This is the master sheet, that all other sheets refer to and has the pricing in column E:(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yoWTQoFFjSOgB2ewugfF_ga-tm_OS-s4JtQVxIX_vTs/edit?usp=sharing)

This is the sheet that needs to pull the price from column E:
(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nvw6wTJcwCXJbDJjA7D7tIPaM6m5CLicuAuceNN749k/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you allow editing rights so that I try some formula?

Comment: Clear out column E of sheet 'Protein' then enter in E2 ={"¨Price"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), VLOOKUP(A3:A,IMPORTRANGE("1Mu-mK3lxfRmK3_wQ4m8C_mqVY0BJOzWX4Uo01d-YZ7U","'Protein'!A3:500"),5,0),))}

Comment: I could not enter it myself (and test it) because of protected ranges in the sheet.

Comment: I unlocked it. But all the formulas come back with blank results as if it is not recognizing the cells in column E as numbers.

Comment: Is it a VALUE that needs to be added? But everything is coming back N/A

Comment: Please remove the range protection in column E.

Comment: I just saw that column was locked. Everything is now unlocked